# Text drawing "bold"

Tags: c#, drawing

So I'm writing a program that generates a chart and saves it to PNG. From what I've read, if I were drawing to a window, it doesn't behave this way, but I'm not doing that.

The problem is that when I pass the brush I use to draw the label to another method to do the drawing, sometimes the text comes out looking bold. Also, the Y coordinate seems to have something to do with it, since it happens on every other row of the chart I'm drawing. And it's not a nice bold, either, it's like a gritty, messy looking bold. Some people have suggested changing the text rendering hint to antialiased, and it solves the "bolding" problem, but it doesn't look as nice as ClearType.

Note that none of this happens if I do everything in one method without passing the brush around, which is the most puzzling part of this. Any ideas?

Here's some of the code:

```
        // Draw the timeline.
        int y = 0;
        bool shadeRow = true;
        foreach (TimelineRow row in timeline.chart)
        {
            int rowHeight = row.height + TimelineRow.ROW_GAP;
            if (shadeRow)
            {
                g.FillRectangle(shadeBrush, 0, y, chartWidth, rowHeight);
            }

            // Draw name labels, guidelines, and timeline row.
            g.DrawString(row.name, labelFont, labelBrush, PADDING, (int)Math.Ceiling(y + (float)PADDING / 2));
            for (int i = 0; i < row.years.Length; i++)
            {
                int blockX = labelsWidth + i * TimelineRow.DEFAULT_HEIGHT;
                g.DrawLine(i % 5 == 0 ? yearGridDark : yearGridLight, blockX, y, blockX, y + rowHeight);
            }
            DrawRow(row, g, labelsWidth, y + 8);

            y += rowHeight;
            shadeRow = !shadeRow;
        }

        // Draw the year labels
        int x = labelsWidth;
        for (int year = timeline.startYear; year <= timeline.endYear; year += 5)
        {
            string yearString = Convert.ToString(year);
            int width = (int)g.MeasureString(yearString, labelFont).Width;
            g.DrawString(yearString, labelFont, labelBrush, x - width / 2, y);
            x += 5 * TimelineRow.DEFAULT_HEIGHT;
        }
```

Comment: Can you show us your code and the result it produces? Maybe the Y position is a fraction of a pixel and is causing it to be aligned incorrectly. (Try casting to an int or rounding it before rendering)

Comment: Added some code to the original post. Well I did pass a float for the Y to it on one line for some reason, though changing it to an int didn't help. I was also passing an int to the other DrawString call, and it still looks funky.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the output?

Comment: I've had similar issues with drawing strings.  In my cases, **clearing** the image FIRST with the background color has fixed the problem: `g.Clear(Color.White);`

Comment: Wow, that actually did it. Thanks! For the record, here's what it looked like before: http://mattarriola.uphero.com/images/Metallica.png and compared to how it's supposed to look: http://mattarriola.uphero.com/images/Metallica2.png. I actually had used g.Clear(Color.White) in the main method before moving all the drawing to different methods, so that's probably why when I did the drawing in that method it didn't behave like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar issues with drawing strings. In my cases, clearing the image FIRST with the background color has fixed the problem.

> Wow, that actually did it.

Use [Graphics.Clear()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to set the initial color:

```
Bitamp bmp = new Bitmap(...);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.Clear(Color.White);
// ... now draw with "g" ...
```